# How do I parse a command line string to get each argument using regex?

Tags: php, regex, ssh

I'm working in PHP and trying to parse the information that I get from a configuration file on disk. The line looks like this:

`option ssh      '-p 443 -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -N -T -R 0.0.0.0:2222:localhost:22 root@example.com`

I've tried with regex or with using `awk|cut` under php's `exec` but I'm not having any success.

My ideal return value looks something like this:

```
    return $this->response = array(
      "host" => "example.com",
      "port" => "443",
      "user" => "root",
      "lport" => "22",
      "rport" => "2222"
    );
```

How do I get the arguments I need from the string with RegEx?

Comment: This format is fixed it never changes ?

Comment: That isn't a trivial string to parse, and the solution depends on whether you want to *check* it for validity, or simply *parse* it for the fields you want. You should look at [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: I think you should look at [`getopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) as it looks like you're parsing command line input

Answer (score 2):

it's not pretty and undoubtedly could be improved markedly but it more or less does what was requested, other than the `2222` ???

```
$str="option ssh      '-p 443 -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -N -T -R 0.0.0.0:2222:localhost:22 root@example.com";

$pttn='#(-p (\d{1,3}) .*:(\d+):localhost:(\d+) ((\w+)@(.*)))#';
preg_match( $pttn, $str, $matches );
$response=array( 'user'=>$matches[6], 'port'=>$matches[2], 'host'=>$matches[7], 'lport'=>$matches[4], 'rport'=>$matches[3] );


print_r( $response );

outputs:
--------
Array
(
    [user] => root
    [port] => 443
    [host] => example.com
    [lport] => 22
    [rport] => 2222
)
```

Like I said, not pretty but...